# Why is the WordPress customizer live preview breaking if I don't check if the function exists?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add the "custom background" support for a theme I'm building, so that users can change it in Appearance > Customize > Colors. The button is showing up, and it's working, BUT the color is not displaying in the live preview.

When I inspect the iframe, WordPress is not adding the "custom-background" body tag, and it's not adding the CSS in the head section of the document.

After hours of digging around, I noticed that one of my php files used as a template file contains a function definition. If I check if the function exists, the live preview magically starts working. This works:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'posted_on' ) ) {

  function posted_on() {

  // Stuff here

  }
}
```

This, on the other hand, breaks the live preview:

```
function posted_on() {

  // Stuff here

}
```

Does anybody have any idea why is this happening? Why is omitting the check for the function name breaking the customizer's live preview? I checked the page source code in an HTML validator and it does not have any errors.

Thanks

Comment: By the way, the "posted_on" is just an example. I'm using specific function names and there are no conflicts with other function names.

Comment: I would imagine it's because the function already exists, so the new declaration gives an error